# Javascript that Will Make Objects The Same Size

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

so I have been woking on this code that would hopefully resize a bunch of objects to be the same height as the tallest one.  I structured it in groups so that you could have five separate groups of items that would all size to the height of the tallest element in the group.  I made a custom attribute called "sizeHeightToOther".  The idea is that you would add this to an element and set "sizeHeightToOther" equal to the group ('1', '2', '3', '4', or '5').  Unfortunately, the code is not working.  This is what I have so far.  Any help would be really appreciated, and anyone if welcome to use it one the bug is figured out.

```js
function SizeHeightToOthers() {

  //The following function gets the heights of each element in the element arrays:
  function GetHeights(elementArray) {
    elementHeightArray = new float[elementArray.length];
    for (int i = 1; i < elementArray.length; i++) {
      elementHeightArray[i] = elementArray.height();
    }
    return elementHeightArray;
  }


  //The following function gets the max height from each height array: 
  function GetMaxs(elementHeightArray) {
    var currentValue = elementHeightArray[0];
    for (var i = 1; i < elementHeightArray.length; i++) {
      if (elementHeightArray[i] > currentValue) {
        currentValue = elementHeightArray[i];
      }
    }
    return value;
  }

  //The following function changes all of the heights of the elements in the element array to be the same as the max height from that array.
  function changeHeights(elementArray, elementHeightArray, maxHeight) {
    for (int i = 0; i < elementArray.length; i++) {
      if (elementHeightArray[i] < maxHeight) {
        elementArray[i].height(maxHeight);
      }
    }
  }



  //var numberOfElements = $("[sizeHeightToOtherGroup]").size();
  var elementArrayOne = $("[sizeHeightToOther='1']").toArray();
  var elementArrayTwo = $("[sizeHeightToOther='2']").toArray();
  var elementArrayThree = $("[sizeHeightToOther='3']").toArray();
  var elementArrayFour = $("[sizeHeightToOther='4']").toArray();
  var elementArrayFive = $("[sizeHeightToOther='5']").toArray();


  var elementHieghtArrayOne = GetHeights(elementArrayOne);
  var elementHieghtArrayTwo = GetHeights(elementArrayTwo);
  var elementHieghtArrayThree = GetHeights(elementArrayThree);
  var elementHieghtArrayFour = GetHeights(elementArrayFour);
  var elementHieghtArrayFive = GetHeights(elementArrayFive);

  changeHeights(elementArrayOne, elementHeightArrayOne, GetMaxs(elementHeightArrayOne));
  changeHeights(elementArrayTwo, elementHeightArrayTwo, GetMaxs(elementHeightArrayTwo));
  changeHeights(elementArrayThree, elementHeightArrayThree, GetMaxs(elementHeightArrayThree));
  changeHeights(elementArrayFour, elementHeightArrayFour, GetMaxs(elementHeightArrayFour));
  changeHeights(elementArrayFive, elementHeightArrayFive, GetMaxs(elementHeightArrayFive));
}


$(function() {
      SizeHeightToOthers();
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/6/6f/Smiley_Face.png" sizeHeightToOthers='1' id="faceOne">
  <img src="http://img1.123freevectors.com/wp-content/uploads/new/icon/075-smiley-face-vector-art-free-download-l.png" sizeHeightToOthers='1' id="faceTwo">
</body>
```

I am really sorry if it is something really dumb, I am fairly new to JavaScript, but have a lot of experience in other languages.

Comment: At first glimpse: `GetMaxs` returns `value` instead of `currentValue`

Comment: Is there a specific reason for using an *ancient* jQuery version?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this answers it, but the vars with the getHeights() are misspelled "..hiegth"

```
var elementH  ie  ghtArrayOne
```

so `GetMaxs()` will fail

Answer (score 0):

There are at least a few problems here with the code.  First of all, you're loading an old version of jQuery which does not have the `toArray` method on the jQuery object.  There's also a mismatch between your attribute selector and your actual HTML markup.

The following code should accomplish what you're trying to do.  There are probably some JS idiosyncrasies here that might not be familiar depending on which language you're coming from.  `Math.max.apply(...` is probably the most idiosyncratic.  It is returning the largest height by creating an array of all the elements' heights and then using the `.apply()` method to retrieve the largest value out of the array in a single call.

```js
$(function () {
    var sizeGroups = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

    sizeGroups.forEach(function (size) {
        sizeToMaxHeight($('[sizeHeightToOthers="' + size + '"]').toArray());
    });

    function sizeToMaxHeight(els) {
        var maxHeight = getMaxHeight(els);

        els.forEach(function (el) {
            $(el).height(maxHeight);
        });

        function getMaxHeight(els) {
            return Math.max.apply(null, els.map(function (el) {
                return $(el).height();
            }));
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<body>
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/6/6f/Smiley_Face.png" sizeHeightToOthers='1' id="faceOne">
  <img src="http://img1.123freevectors.com/wp-content/uploads/new/icon/075-smiley-face-vector-art-free-download-l.png" sizeHeightToOthers='1' id="faceTwo">
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This was great!